# How to get unique data for product?

Tags: sql

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, realPriceBrutto FROM table WHERE quantity > 0 order by product_id, realPriceBrutto;
```

, but in my result I've got 3 different values for some id ( 
195 - 39.68, 195 - 43.19...)
I need the lowest value of realPriceBrutto for product_id.
I have also tried :

```
select * from table 
where (product_id,realPriceBrutto) IN (select product_id,min(realPriceBrutto) from table group by product_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `group by` the product_id, and select the min() of realPriceBrutto.

```
SELECT 
    product_id, min(realPriceBrutto)
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    quantity > 0 
group by
    product_id
order by 
    product_id
```